# Amazon SES: Email address is not verified

Tags: amazon-web-services, verification, amazon-ses

I have an AWS Account and a verified domain and also a verified email address in that domain (both items have been verified by Amazon, except for the DKIM for now)

After I tried to send an email with a source account equals to support@mydomainverified.com to another of my email accounts from the AWS webpage (with the send test email button) I get the following error: Email address is not verified

The domain and the email address from that domain are verified. I also already added a payment method to the billing information. What else amazon want me to do?

[Even Amazon Rejects in their Send Test Email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAbxg.png)

Comment: If I verify the receiver email address, the email is beign sent successfully. But I am not able to send to any other email address. Where can I enable to send to anyone an email?

Answer (score 8):

I have found the solution. I put it here if anyone needs it.

The account is enabled for sandbox only. To move to production environment and send email to anyone, you have to follow these instructions: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html

Good luck!